# Read C++ binary file in R

Tags: r, rcpp

Can I read a binary file written by C++ in R?

I have been using Rcpp in my R package and the simulations typically generate a large amount of data. I am planning to write the output to binary files in C++ and then read those back in R. This works if I write as text files but I didn't find a solution with binary files. The program sometimes crashes abruptly if I pass data using many NumericVectors (I am yet to fully understand the memory management using Rcpp).

Can this approach enable me to share larger datasets between C++ and R compared to what is possible by passing vectors? In C++, the maximum vector size is limited by RAM and address bus (may be?) but I think R is able to load larger vectors using swap. Am I correct or misunderstanding the concepts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can. But it's "complicated".

You are embarking on a topic called binary serialization. There is a *lot* of work out there.  In essence you are somewhere in the continum between of

- minimal: open a file, write out N binary items; then on the other side read N binaries. We did something similar at work years ago where wrote some metadata with `<rows,cols,version>` and then a binary blob of `rows * cols` double to attach to a matrix
- maximal: use a fully descriptive meta language like Protocol Buffer or MessagePack to describe the binary content, write it in C++ (using the appropriate library) and read in back in R (using the corresponding packages---I am involved with one each: RProtoBuf and RcppMsgPack).

And a lot in between.  If you *really* only need to communicate between C(++) and R you could try the RData / rds format.  There is one library:  [librdata](https://github.com/WizardMac/librdata) and I experimented with it (and filed some bug reports and made some pull requests). I might start there.

So in short: do some research, figure out what to do and then do it :)

PS If you call C++ via Rcpp from R then you may not need files.  We can pass large object back and forth -- the limit may be your RAM.

Comment: @ Dirk Eddelbuettel
Thanks for the references. As I am heavily relying on Rcpp and BH, RcppMsgPack looks promising (primarily because of the exceptional help provided by you and others in the Rcpp ecosystem). Currently, I am passing objects back and forth and I am sure that my objects are not larger than RAM size but the program still crashes sometimes. I think I need to check explicitly for deep copies.

Comment: Debug it carefully.  If you assign to `Rcpp::NumericMatrix`, say, then no copy is made.  Also see [our paper on RcppMsgPack](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2018/RJ-2018-068/index.html) which just came out.